# Looking for a book with all math formulas & theorem

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm really into mathematics, but I often forget little things and have to look them up on Wikipedia. This doesn't work when I'm backpacking though since I'll be days away from any internet access. I recently forgot how to multiply matrices and it was quite irritating to wait to get hold of a computer to continue my studies. I'm wondering if there's a book with every math formula & theorem, from $a+b=b+a$ to fractional derivatives. I don't want it to have explanations, just formulas & theorems. If it doesn't exist, do you think it would sell well?

I understand that math isn't very linear, so it's very difficult to have a book of formulas without missing anything.

Comment: I bet such a book would be very looooooooooooooong.

Comment: A book with *everything* in it would likely be way over your carry-on limit. Since you mentioned Wikipedia, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Offline_Wikipedia_readers).

Comment: I found it.  Well, not **all** formulas, only 1300 of them.  https://webéducation.com/book-1300-math-formulas-pdf/

Answer (score 1):

How about a book like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123742889)? Or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439835489)?

Answer (score 0):

[Schaum's Outline of Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071795375) is a good start point for this kind of book.